# flask autocompletion with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I went through several of howtos about enabling autocompletion via jquery but still kind of stucked on one think. I hope I can get any advices how to make my code work.

python code:

```
# autocompletion
@app.route('/autocomplete', methods=['GET'])
def autocomplete():
    results = []
    search = request.args.get('term')
    print search
    results.append(db.Execution.select().where(db.regexp(db.Execution.identifier, search)))
    return jsonify(results)
```

form.py:

```
class DiffFrom(Form):
    identifierA = TextField('identifierA',
        validators=[validators.Optional()])
```

template:

```
<!-- jquery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

    <script type=text/javascript>
    $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ url_for("autocomplete") }}'
        }).done(function (data) {
            $('#identifierA').autocomplete({
                source: data,
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
    })
    </script>

<form class="form-inline" role="form" name="form" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <!-- identifier input field -->
         {{ form.identifierA(size=10, placeholder="Identifier", class="form-control", title="Regexp accepted") }}
 </form>
```

The print in #automation outputs None, which is not correct IMHO. Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: You don't pass any data to the `.ajax()` function. This is not a flask question.

Comment: OK so in that case what should be the right solution?

Comment: Look at the "Examples" section in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/